# Django Rest Framework - Failed lookup for key [form] in u'None'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-errors

I recently updated Django Rest Framework to version 3.3.1. After I did so, I get the following error: `Failed lookup for key [form] in u'None'`

It is coming when I visit this view:

```
class SearchListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SearchMyUserSerializer
    filter_backends = (
        filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
        filters.SearchFilter,
        filters.OrderingFilter,
    )
    search_fields = ('^username', '^full_name',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        full_name = self.request.query_params.get('full_name', None)

        if username and full_name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username, full_name=full_name)
        elif username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
        elif full_name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(full_name=full_name)
        return queryset
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `filter_backends`, I just needed to remove `filters.DjangoFilterBackend`. It works fine now.